# MongodB $switch to filter null values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hi im trying to use switch in mongodb but I think there is something wrong with the case

```
"filterdiscontinued":{
$switch:{
branches: [
{case: {$and: [ {$eq: ["$ogstat.valuedescription","Discontinued"] }, {$eq: ["$patientorderitems.dispensebatchdetail.assignquantity",null] }     ] }, then: "Remove"}
],
default: "$ogstat.valuedescription"
}
}
```

Basically im trying to get the data with discontinue status and a null value in patientorderitems.dispensebatchdetail.assignquantity.

Hope someone can give me a better query for this. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong, are you getting output that's not what you expect? Could you include a sample document and an example of the output you want?

Comment: The `$eq` operator does not consider `null` and `undefined` to be equal.

Comment: {case: {$and: [ {$eq: ["$ogstat.valuedescription","Discontinued"] }, {$eq: [ {$ifNull : ["$patientorderitems.dispensebatchdetail.assignquantity", 0 ] },0] }     ] } , then: "Remove"}

Comment: I did some adjustment, using $ifNull will be more useful than $eq:null